# How can access bunch of <li>?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of texts and I want to change their innerHTML. how can I do that by javascript if I have thousands of li tag (whose data come from database)?

```
<div>
<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>as</li>
<li>asd</li>
<li>asds</li>
<li>asdsa</li>
<li>asdsad</li>
<li>asdsadz</li>
<li>asdsadzc</li>
....
.....
</ul>
</div>
```

-Thanks.

**Update**
JS code being used:

```
function a(){
    var parent = document.getElementById("z");
    var i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= parent.children.length; i++){
        if(parent.children[i].tagName == "LI"){
            if(i%2!=0){
                parent.children[i].innerHTML="ok";
            }
        }
    }
}
document.onload=a(); // this didn't work. so I called the function in body tag instead of that.
<body onload="a();">
```

Comment: You... select them and iterate over them: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Traversing_the_DOM.

Comment: What server side language are you using? PHP? .net? You say they are coming from the database? is this an ajax response? do you need the html of the li's to be altered after the page is rendered or can we use the server side script to format the li's content?

Comment: if I try getElementById then its so tough to give id for each li tag, and I can't try getElementByTagName cause there could be other li tags on the page.I'm using php to draw data from database.

Comment: is it possible to give same id to all li tags and get length that id li ?

Comment: possible, but not good : id's imply uniqueness

Comment: @user1844626 you shouldn't do that, try using classes for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using `getElementsByTagName` ? Sonds like it would help you find the elements you're trying to work with.

**Edit**

If you can give an Id to the UL element that holds the li's you're trying to process, you could do something like this:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("yourID");
var i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++){ 
  if(parent.children[i].tagName == "LI") { 
     //do what you want...
   }
}
```

**EDit 2**

You have to change the last line on your script:

```
document.onload=a();
```

With this one: `window.onload=a;`

That'll get your function to execute on the onLoad event. Note that there might be some crossbrowser incompatibility, I would suggest researching a bit on how to execute functions on the onload event on a crossbrowser manner, or just adding this to your body tag:

```
<body onload="a();">
```

Comment: http://snippets.jc21.com/snippets/javascript/getelementsbytagname-cross-browse/   , if you want it cross browsing proof

Comment: Sorry,I can't try getElementsByTagName cause there could be other li tags on the page.

Comment: is it possible to give same id to all li tags and get length that id li ?

Comment: @user1844626 I added an edit, with a different way to iterating over the li's, let me know if that helps.

Comment: @Deleteman : he should give them a class instead of an id.., he wants to duplicate id's to select li's

Comment: @Peter Yes giving them a class to the li's or an ID to their parent works pretty much the same way IMHO.

Comment: I gave id 'z' to ul tage and tried this >> var parent = document.getElementById("z");
var i = 0;
for(i = 0; i <= parent.children.length; i++){ 
  if(i%2!=0) { 
    parent.children[i].innerHTML="ok";
   }
}
} but not working

Comment: @user1844626 You need to check if the tagname is "LI", I think you might be finding the "text nodes" between the tags...

Comment: I did that too >> var parent = document.getElementById("z");
var i = 0;
for(i = 0; i <= parent.children.length; i++){ 
if(parent.children[i].tagName == "LI") { 
  if(i%2!=0) { 
    parent.children[i].innerHTML="ok";
   }
}
}

Comment: var parent = document.getElementById("z");
alert(parent.children.length);  << its not working,so it seems the length not going there.(I tried on mozilla firefox latest version and IE 6)

Comment: Check out the fiddle I posted on my previous comment... or update the question's text with your new HTML and your JS

Comment: I saw your link, but thats not working here. heres my entire code >> <script type="text/javascript"><!--
function a(){var parent = document.getElementById("z");var i = 0;
for(i = 0; i <= parent.children.length; i++){if(parent.children[i].tagName == "LI"){if(i%2!=0){     parent.children[i].innerHTML="ok";
}}}}document.onload=a();--></script><div><ul id="z"><li>a</li><li>as</li><li>asd</li><li>asds</li><li>asdsa</li><li>asdsad</li><li>asdsadz</li><li>asdsadzc</li></ul></div>  would you please copy paste my code to your editor ? don't know whats the problem here.

Comment: thank you so much, its working now. just called the function in < body > tag

Comment: onload event in body tag may be better than others. so its better to use in body tag whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Given the - not so far fetched - precondition you wish to use jQuery, you can select them and iterate over them with "each".

```
$("li").each( 
function() { $(this).html("changed content"); }
);
```

If you are not using jQuery, using a js-library that helps you out with the quircky dom is probably not a bad idea...

The general idea

1. Select nodes
2. Iterate and change html

is always the same.

Comment: He doens't specify if he's using any kind of library... so the "$" can actually fail.

Comment: jQuery isn't mentioned, but it probably should be

Comment: there could be other li tags on the page.

Comment: is it possible to give same id to all li tags and get length that id li ?

Comment: @user1844626 : then you should update your selector ($"li") .   If it's only the li's in a div with id "thisid" it becomes : "$("div#thisid li") for example, all is possible.  If you are really planning to use eihter vanilla javascript or jquery on the dom (html structure) you should do some effort to study it, it will pay off.

Comment: @user1844626 : you should not give the same id to different tags : id implies uniqueness, you should  give them the same class instead

Comment: then how can I get how many li tags are with id 'something' ?

Comment: $("li.something").length (in jquery that is) if your li's have class somethin (<li class="something">)

Comment: sorry I'm messing up, the idea is >> var i=0; a for loop will run 0 to the number of li tags and if the number is odd then the innerHTML will be 'ok'. I don't know jquery so its messy here.